# Why does this call to anonymous function does not work?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Why does this

```
$( '#someid' ).click( function() {
    getdata( 'listing' , function( data ) {
        showlist( data );
    }, 'string' , 1 );
});
```

work but this one doesn't

```
$( '#someid' ).click( function() {
    getdata( 'listing' , showlist( data ), 'string' , 1 );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function( data ) {
        showlist( data );
    }
```

Means that you are passing in an anonymous function

```
showlist( data )
```

Means that you are calling `showList(data)` and pass the returned value to the function.
In case you want to use your second case correctly, fix it like this:

```
$( '#someid' ).click( function() {
    getdata( 'listing' , showlist, 'string' , 1 );
});
```

Comment: Is there a way for the second example so `getdata` knows that the second parameter is a anonymous function and execute it?

Comment: I can't use the `data` parameter though.

Comment: the showList should be called inside the getdata and the getdata should pass in the data for the showList. @MegaNairda

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't work because `getdata` ask a function as a second parameter. In the second example you'are executing the function (and passing its returning value) instead of passing the function itself.

if you write

```
$( '#someid' ).click( function() {
    getdata( 'listing' , showlist, 'string' , 1 );
});
```

without parens `()` it still works, but as you can see, you can't pass anymore the `data` parameter along the function `showlist`

Comment: I see, now I know why the some of the functions runs fine even without the `function(){..}` since they does not have any parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you are executing `showlist(data)` and putting its result value as a `getdata()` parameter.

You could imagine, that this:

```
getdata( 'listing' , showlist( data ), 'string' , 1 );
```

is a logical equivalent of this:

```
var temp = showlist( data );
getdata( 'listing', temp, 'string', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the first is passing a function as the second argument to `getdata`, while the second is passing *the result of calling a function*.

You could write the second correctly as

```
$( '#someid' ).click( function() {
    getdata( 'listing' , showlist, 'string' , 1 );
});
```

We are no longer *calling* `showlist` here, rather allowing `getdata` to call it later on.